# Find a number from the remainders modulo two integers

Tags: number-theory

If the remainder of the division of $n$ by 7 equals 5, what is the remainder of the division of $2n$ by 7?

Comment: It is a bad practice to edit the question, not describing it.

Comment: `Simplify[Mod[2 n, 7], Assumptions -> Mod[n, 7] == 5]`

Comment: sorry i need this one

Comment: @Ritaana: The pleasure is all mine. Regard.

Comment: thank you, i have one day to prepare to my exam , after that i will make more search ...

Comment: This belongs on math.SE, if it belongs anywhere. Voted to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in such a way.

```
FullSimplify[Mod[n, 3], Assumptions -> Mod[n, 6] == 5]
```

> `2`

I leave your second question on your own.

Comment: `FullSimplify[Mod[2*n, 7], Assumptions -> Mod[n, 7] == 5]` answers the edited question.